# Eclipse template for generating list values in enum

Tags: java, eclipse, templates, enums

I usually need to iterate/get an enum value by it index. Enum.values() is not enough, because it makes the code too verbose whenever i want to work with these values.

I want a template for eclipse which, given an enum:

```
enum E { a, b, c, d }
```

generates an static list on the inside:

```
enum E { 
    a, b, c, d
    public final static List<E> values = Arrays.asList(values());
    public final static int total = values().length;//Bonus point
    public final static E getByIndex(int index) { return values()[index]; }//Bonus point
}
```

Comment: How is `E.getByIndex(i)` less verbose than `E.values()[i]`?

Comment: heh, you are right. In this case, it could make use of the generaed values list. Each call to values() generate a new array. Anyway, my main question is about the generation of that list with templates.